# Attention mechanism used for text completion task is attending to future tokens

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import os
import warnings
import torch.nn.functional as F
import math

class DecoderSequential(nn.Sequential):
    @staticmethod
    def is_key_duplicate(dictionary, key_to_check):
            count = 0
            for key in dictionary:
                if key == key_to_check:
                    count += 1
                    if count > 1:
                        return True
            return False
    def forward(self, input_ids, **kwargs):
        for module in self:
            try:
                input = self.embedding(input_ids)
            except Exception as e:
                input = input_ids
                pass
            if "input_ids" in kwargs:
                kwargs.pop("input_ids", None)
            if isinstance(module, nn.Embedding):
                continue
            try:
                output = module(input_ids=input, **kwargs)
            except:
                output = module(input, **kwargs)
            try:
                input = output.last_hidden_state
            except:
                input = output[0]
            

        return output

class Attention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_head, d_model):
        super().__init__()
        assert d_model % n_head == 0
        self.n_head = n_head
        self.head_dim = d_model // n_head
        self.d_model = d_model
        self.wq = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model)
        self.wk = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model)
        self.wv = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model)
        self.wo = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model)
    def forward(self, q, k, v, attention_mask=None):
        bsz, q_len, _ = q.size()
        if attention_mask is None:
            attention_mask = self.generate_causal_mask(q)
        q = self.wq(q)
        k = self.wk(k)
        v = self.wv(v)
        q = q.view(bsz, q_len, self.n_head, self.head_dim).transpose(1,2)
        k = k.view(bsz, q_len, self.n_head, self.head_dim).transpose(1,2)
        v = v.view(bsz, q_len, self.n_head, self.head_dim).transpose(1,2)
        attn = torch.matmul(q, k.transpose(2, 3)) / math.sqrt(self.head_dim)
        attn = attn + attention_mask
        attn = F.softmax(attn, dim=-1)
        attn = torch.matmul(attn, v).transpose(1, 2).contiguous()
        attn = attn.reshape(bsz, q_len, self.d_model)
        return self.wo(attn)
    def generate_causal_mask(self, x):
        mask = torch.triu(torch.ones(x.size(0), 1, x.size(1), x.size(1)), diagonal=1).to(x.device)
        return mask
class CMLP(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Conv1d(d_model, d_model * 4, kernel_size=1)
        self.fc2 = nn.Conv1d(d_model * 4, d_model, kernel_size=1)
        self.act = nn.SiLU()
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.fc2(self.act(self.fc1(x.transpose(1, 2)))).transpose(1, 2)
class Block(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, n_head):
        super().__init__()
        self.d_model = d_model
        self.n_head = n_head
        self.attention = Attention(n_head, d_model)
        self.cmlp = CMLP(d_model)
    def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask=None):
        hidden_states = input_ids
        residual = hidden_states
        hidden_states = self.attention(
            hidden_states,
            hidden_states,
            hidden_states,
            attention_mask=attention_mask
        )
        hidden_states = hidden_states + residual
        residual = hidden_states
        hidden_states = self.cmlp(hidden_states)
        hidden_states = hidden_states + residual
        return hidden_states
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,
                vocab_size,
                d_model,
                n_layer,
                n_head):
        super().__init__()
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, d_model)
        self.decoder_layers = DecoderSequential()
        for i in range(n_layer):
            decoder = Block(d_model, n_head)
            self.decoder_layers.add_module(f"decoder_layer {i}", decoder)
        self.lm_head = nn.Linear(d_model, vocab_size)
    def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask=None, labels=None):
        hidden_states = input_ids
        hidden_states = self.embedding(hidden_states)
        hidden_states = self.decoder_layers(hidden_states, attention_mask=attention_mask)
        logits = self.lm_head(hidden_states)
        if labels is not None:
            loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(logits.view(-1, logits.size(-1)), labels.view(-1))
        return loss, logits
```

The code attached implements a simple decoder-only transformer that will be trained on a text completion task. However, I've noticed an issue where the attention mechanism attends to future tokens. I have made sure the attention mask is being passed correctly, and I also get a feeling the issue may not have to do with the attention mechanism itself. Can someone help me resolve this issue?

Note: I do already have positional encoding implemented but I have removed it to keep this short.

I've inspected the forward propagation of the attention mechanism, and it seems to match up with the equation for attention. I've also made sure that the attention mask is being passed through the forward propagation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.